# Как избавиться от потери строк Buffered Reader/Writer

Tags: java

Суть в следующем:
Читаю файл построчно с помощью BufferedReader

```
BF = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
```

Затем обрабатываю строки (удаляю неугодные символы/слова)
 И записываю обратно

```
PrintWriter PW = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(Filenew)));
String C;
long lineCounter = 0L;
while (((C=BF.readLine())!=null)) {
    C = CensorLine(C);
    if (C == null) {
        PW.flush();
        PW.close();
        BF.close();
        break;
    }
    String censored = CensorOr(C);
    PW.println(censored);
    //PW.append('\n');

    if (lineCounter % 500L == 0L) {
        PW.flush();
    }
    ++lineCounter;
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я заканчиваю читать файл  if (C == null)

Я останавливаю и запись в файл, и как следствие - теряю несколько последних строчек файла (около 10). Подскажите, как избавиться от потери строк.

Comment: Метод `CensorLine` может возвращать null? И чем отличаются методы `CensorLine` и `CensorOr`? Если при `C == null` не нужно заканчивать читать и писать файлы - так не заканчивайте читать и писать, заменив `break` на `continue` или ещё как. Главное ресурсы закрыть не забыть, для чего хорошо бы подошла конструкция try-with-resources

Comment: В Java, кстати, принято название переменных и методов писать с маленькой буквы. А полностью заглавными пишутся только константы

Comment: А зачем тогда проверка `C` на null?

Comment: @Regent
Метод CensorLine не может возвращать null.
Метод CensorLine от CensorOr обрабатывают строку полученную от BF, CensorLine вырезает некоторые значения по регулярке, CensorOr извлекают подстроку из CensorLine.
П.С. по поводу нейминга понял, спасибо

Comment: А, ну теоретически C может быть null, если это конец документа (строка пустая)

Comment: То есть метод `CensorLine` всё-таки возвращает null? Но только в том случае, когда на вход ему приходит null?

Comment: Да. Я кажется понял о чем вы, попробовал сделать проверку:
     _if (censored == null) {
                                PW.flush();
                                PW.close();
                                break;
                            }_

В итоге я потерял рекордно мало строк, 4)))

Comment: Я, на самом деле, не понимаю с какой проблемой вы столкнулись: непонятно где тут могут теряться какие-то строки из файла. Если при прочтении очередной строки (`C = BF.readLine()`) переменная `C` будет равна null, то тело while-а вообще не выполнится (надеюсь, у вас есть закрытие `PW` после while-a). Если же `C` не null, то и `CensorLine(C)` вернёт не null (с ваших слов). В итоге `if (C == null)` никогда не выполняется. И единственный способ совершить ошибку здесь - не закрыть `PW` после while-a

Comment: Действительно. 
Ошибка была в том, что я не закрывал PW после цикла. Спасибо.

Comment: На здоровье. Я тогда оформлю это ответом, чтобы вопрос был решен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если при прочтении очередной строки (`C = BF.readLine()`) переменная `C` будет равна null, то тело while-а не выполнится.
Соответственно, в теле цикла `C` не равна null, поэтому `CensorLine(C)` также не вернёт не null (исходя из комментариев к вопросу).
В итоге условие `if (C == null)` всегда ложно. Это приводит к тому, что `PW` не закрывается (так как после `while` его закрытия нет), что чревато потерей результатов.

Нужно добавить закрытие ресурсов после цикла. А для избежания подобных проблем можно пользоваться конструкций [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newFileName))
{
    String line;
    int lineCounter = 0;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String censored = cencorOr(cencorLine(line));
        writer.println(censored);

        lineCounter++;
        if (lineCounter == 500)
        {
            writer.flush();
            lineCounter = 0;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```